# Layout webpage information that is pulled from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm not even sure how to ask this question, but here goes. I'm building a webpage that lets you select a test from a drop down menu, and when you click submit it is supposed to load all the questions onto the page that are associated with that test. My problem is with the layout. Here is a static version of what I am attempting to do:

[image]

I need the site to pull all the necessary questions from the database and lay them out one at a time with the 5 buttons, or radio buttons, beneath them. There are a different number of questions for every test, so I basically need the site to continue building this layout until it runs out of questions. I hope that makes sense. I've been working mostly Dreamweaver with PHP, HTML and MySQL up to this point. How might I go about accomplishing something like this, or at the very least how would I get started? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Building dynamic webpages is a very basic web programming skill. I will give you a very basic idea of approaching this problem.

In your case, you need to have a container in your HTML markup that will contain all the questions. A PHP script will connect to your database, execute query to get all questions for the selected test and load them into your container.

You can find more information on building dynamic web pages at www.w3schools.com

From the comment, I want to add that you should put all questions under a form container. Build a component consisting of 5 radio buttons and inject the component in your HTML right after you inject a question. This process would continue till all questions have been included.

Hope this gives a better insight to the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I am familiar with dynamic page building, and that's no really the issue. My problem is getting it to add in the buttons after every question when it is adding them to the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into loops. You could do it like this :

Do a query (using PDO in php for example, look it up) on your questions table.

lets say the variable that holds the result of that query is called $result , then you can do a php loop like this :

```
foreach($result as $value){
// You put the code you want here , 
//like printing the line with the question ,
//and making the buttons
}
```

The foreach loops repeats the things you put between the brackets until it has no more results to process.

Resources to get you started :

PHP loops:
http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_looping_for.asp

Database communication using PDO :
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 0):

well first you'll need your questions within a database. I'm also assuming you have clients that can access this? Multiple tests too.

First off build you sql tables within a database.

```
CREATE TABLE questions(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMEMNT,
    question varchar(255),
    testID int(10),
);
CREATE TABLE tests(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) UNIQUE,
);
CREATE TABLE clients(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMEMNT,
    username varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    count int(10) DEFAULT 0,
);
```

Now I normally use an administrative mysql software to manage and build my tables, so you may want to check I have the correct syntax. But the basic idea is to build your tables.

Now that you've got your tables build, you can progress onto inserting your data. I'll give you two examples, just incase you're not using a third party sql software:

```
INSERT INTO tests (name) VALUES ('am I a coder');
```

The above is a simple `insert` into your mysql database. These can get more complex and if you want to develop into php and mysql queries. I suggest you progress into mySQLi and sql's features and abilities before progressing further. 
Because I added `unique` to the column `name` in tests. This means the data within the column cannot be repeated/duplicated. Using the above as an example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tests (name) VALUES('am I a coder');
```

The above will ignore the `insert` if there is already an entry where the column `name` is 'am I a coder'.
The above queries will produce an entry like this:

```
ID |      name
1  |  'am I a coder'
```

Another two quick examples

```
INSERT INTO questions (question,testID) VALUES('your chosen question','1');
INSERT INTO clients (username,password) VALUES('me','password');
```

Now with PHP you can select data, insert data and update data to name a few, using the above quires plus more possibilities. Here is a small idea of what you can do with PHP to access data in our tables.
mySQLi is the easiest and preferred method by novices. Please note mySQL is depreciated and I wouldn't recommend using.
There are also two methods, procedural and object orientated. I prefer orientated as it's neater and well, I'm used to it but I'll provide procedural so you can decide as of which you'd like to start with. 
Procedural

```
$connection=mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','database');
//some people add a `die` onto connections but I don't see the point if you're 100% sure it'll connect.
$result=mysqli_prepare($connection,"SELECT * FROM tests");//I like prepared statments over queries because they're more secure.
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result,$ID,$name);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)){
    $tests[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'name'=>$name);
}
mysqli_stmt_close($result);
```

OOP

```
$DBH=new mysqli('host','username','password','datbase');
$get=$DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM tests');
$get->execute();
$get->bind_result($ID,$name)
while($get->fetch()){
    $tests[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'name'=>$name);
}
```

Now with PHP we have this handle thing called a `foreach` loop! If you've used arrays in javascript before within a `for` loop it's kind of similar to `for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)` BUT! it's even better!

Because our $test is an array and structured like this `tests=array(0=>array('ID'=>1,'name'=>'am I a coder'))` we can use the foreach loop to process each test array entry and build your select drop down.

```
foreach($tests as $test){
    $options.="<option value='".$test['ID']."'>".$test['name']."</option>";//within strings, using full stops as '+'. adds `strings` together in other words.
}
```

Now we've built the options to go in the select. Best put it all together.

```
echo "<select name='tests'>".$options."</options>";
```

Because PHP is a server side script, it'll process all data before sending the document HTML to the client. (Basic explanation) So 'echoing' to the body will process the HTML. There are other methods, but this is the easiest for now.

Now we've got out tests. The next step is to build the form to build the test up.
so this could look like this:

```
<form name='whichTest' action='destination.php' method="POST">
    <select name="tests">
        <?php echo $options; ?>
    </select>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' value='select'/>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted. it will be 'sent' to whatever directory is in your action attribute within the form tag. The form data there will be within a handle variable named `$_POST`. Which was specified by the form attribute method.
isn't coding exciting you ask yourself!! :D 
could it get anymore for-filling!!! it just might!!

I know if you're a beginner I may be rushing you into things but this is what would be required if you're to build what you've specified! So if you're not following up to this stage, best practise, practise, practise! I'm self taught so to others I chat a load of rubbish :D lol

Now with your $_POST variable. We can use it to make a query to our database to return data to be handled within the `foreach` as I wrote earlier! Sometimes I wish this was like Bluepeter and I could just lean over and go HERE'S ONE I MADE EARLIER! But no I gotta write stuff! D:
Right! Anyway!

```
$get=$DBH->prepare('SELECT ID,question FROM questions WHERE testID=?');//notice the question mark?
$get->bind_param('i',$_POST['tests']);//This will 'insert' into our query, the data within variable $_POST['tests'] avoiding sql injection
//the name of the input's within the form are now the key within the array $_POST
//it's considered bad practise to directly insert the $_POST variable into the query but it's only an example. Calm down Your Common Sense! 
$get->execute();//executes the prepared statement
$get->bind_result($ID,$question);
while($get->fetch()){
    $questions[]=array('ID'=>$ID,'question'=>$question);
}
$get->close();
foreach($questions as $q){
    echo"<h3>".$q['question']."</h3>";
    //build your button system here.
}
```

That's pretty much JUST the basics you need to know on how to build your tests. There's probably better methods that you could plan and build knowing the capabilities of sql and your requirements. I know I haven't touched much on the client's table but I'm sure you'll figure it out ;) 
Anyway, I'm off to dig out some bluepeter videos or something. Peace out!

Oh! And remember, if it's too much to learn in one go, do it in stages.

1. Firstly, insure PHP and SQL is installed on your server. There are
   many free ones out there if you're learning/practising.
2. Secondly, build your tables within SQL and add your data to them.
3. Thirdly, 'get' your data from the tables you've built.
4. Next you want to structure your data `dynamically` using arrays
   (data you've received and structured yourself)
5. Then build your responses
6. And of course! Develop and improve your result!